# Message Passing with UIView as delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have written a third party framework that displays a UIView on top of the existing view of the calling app, i.e., the app calls the framework/SDK and the SDK shows a UIView on top of the view that is currently on screen.

This is done by the use of delegates. The app sets the current view on screen as the delegate to the framework. The framework then uses this delegates and adds its own UIView as a subview using the code:

```
[[self delegate] addSubview:myVc.view];
```

where `myVc` is the ViewController in the framework.

Now I need to pass a method back to the calling app saying the view was shown on screen. Since, the delegate is a UIView, how do I pass a message to the calling class?

The reason why I have asked for a UIView delegate is because my UIView takes only a part of screen and I need the other part of the screen to show the remaining part of the app and be active. When I used ViewController as a delegate, it resulted in the other part of the screen being black instead of transparent.

So my question is how do I pass a message to the calling app, which calls the SDK and sets its view as a delegate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can post a notification that the caller listens for or you can accept a block as a parameter from the caller and execute that when the view is shown.

Comment: I don't have control over the app. So can't use the notification option. Could you elaborate the blocks please? Thanks

Comment: No matter what you do, the part that calls your framework has to implement something that reacts when you tell it that the action is complete.  In the options I mentioned, it can either listen for a notification or it can pass in some code (a block) that you execute for the caller.  If you need some more information about how blocks work, try Apple's on-line Objective-C docs.  But, whatever you "send", something has to be prepared to "receive" it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then you simply need to define protocol :

.h

```
@protocol YourFrameWorkViewDelegate <NSObject>
     - (void)yourFrameWorkViewDidAppear;
@end

@interface YouFrameWorkView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <YourFrameWorkViewDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation YouFrameWorkView
- (void)didMoveToWindow
{
   if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(yourFrameWorkViewDidAppear)]) {
    [self.delegate yourFrameWorkViewDidAppear];
   }
}
@end
```

or you could call delegate from your VC like

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
if ([self.view.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(yourFrameWorkViewDidAppear)]) {
    [self.view.delegate yourFrameWorkViewDidAppear];
}
```

Of course any app that wants to use you frame work needs to implement that protocol. This would probably be rootVCs view would have to be subclass and implement your protocol. This is standard practice. Hope it helped.

Follow up after your comment:

Masure that view implements your protocol

.h

```
@interface ViewThatUsesYourFrameWork : UIView <YourFrameWorkViewDelegate>

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation ViewThatUsesYourFrameWork

- (void)yourFrameWorkViewDidAppear
{

}
@end
```

and also confirm that delegate is indeed set.
before you call respondsToSelector

```
if(!self.delegate)NSLog(@"Delegate is not set")
```

Comment: I have this implemented at the moment. Unfortunately, I get UIView cannot respond to selector error.

Comment: Added some follow up to my answer in light of your comment